# how to add other mac address using this vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

my vba is

```
    Public Function notmacaddress()

    Dim m As String
    Const test = "11:11:11:11:11:11"
    
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    If m <> test Then
        notmacaddress = True
    Else
        notmacaddress = False
    End If
    
    End Function

    Function GetMACAddress() As String
        Dim sComputer As String
        Dim oWMIService As Object
        Dim cItems As Object
        Dim oItem As Object
        Dim myMacAddress As String
    
        sComputer = "."
    
        Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    
        Set cItems = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
    
        For Each oItem In cItems
            If Not IsNull(oItem.IPAddress) Then myMacAddress = oItem.macAddress
            Exit For
        Next
        'it will return mac address in format MM:MM:MM:SS:SS:SS
        GetMACAddress = myMacAddress
    End Function
    
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       If notmacaddress Then
          ThisWorkbook.Close
       End If
    End Sub
```

how to add other mac address in code??? For example:  `"11:11:11:11:11:11"` `"22:22:34:32:55:23"` `"34:45:45:33:33:11"`

Excel just in mac address system To run.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next adapted function, please:

```
Public Function notMACAddress() As Boolean
    Dim m As String, arrMAC As Variant, El As Variant
    Const test = "11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:34:32:55:23,34:45:45:33:33:11"
    'add above the MAC string you need to be checked (separated by comma)
    
    arrMAC = Split(test, ",")
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    For Each El In arrMAC
        If m = El Then
            notMACAddress = False: Exit Function
        End If
    Next El
    notMACAddress = True
End Function
```

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub checkMACAddress()
    Debug.Print GetMACAddress
    Debug.Print notMACAddress
End Sub
```

It allows adding of how many MAC addresses, separated by comma, you need.

You can use the function in this way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If notMACAddress Then ThisWorkbook.Close
End If
```

But, if the workbook is open with macro disabled...

Comment: I think he wants a UDF where you can pass the cell value in to the function and use that as the test. Hard to  tell.

Comment: it did not work. Excel only opens at the first MAC address ;( , i want open excel in all three mac addreses.

Comment: @wolf: Dis is not possible. Please copy the function like it is and test it as I suggested, using `Sub checkMACAddress`. This sub will return the current MAC and the result of function processing. Put the current MAC inside the string and then take it out and check the function return for both situations. It should work well. But, refresh the page (this one) and use the function like it is. I made a small modification at about 5 minutes after I posted it. Does the function you use have the next code line: `If m = El Then`? If yes, it is the updated one and I cannot understand how you use it...

Comment: Public Function notmacaddress1()

    Dim m As String
    Const test = "11:11:11:11:13:25"
    
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    If m <> test Then
        notmacaddress1 = True
    Else
        notmacaddress1 = False
    End If
    
    End Function
    Public Function notmacaddress2()

    Dim m As String
    Const test = "22:22:22:22:49:43"
    
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    If m <> test Then
        notmacaddress2 = True
    Else
        notmacaddress2 = False
    End If
    
    End Function

Comment: Public Function notmacaddress3()

    Dim m As String
    Const test = "33:33:33:84:49:43"
    
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    If m <> test Then
        notmacaddress3 = True
    Else
        notmacaddress3 = False
    End If
    
    End Function

Comment: how set IF in code? :

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If notmacaddress1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    
    ElseIf notmacaddress2 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    
    ElseIf notmacaddress3 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    
    Else
    
End If
End Sub

Comment: @wolf: Firstly, **does the above function return what it should**? Do you understand how to use it? Then, do not try writing code in comments. We cannot understand too much. If you need to specify something, try editing your code and place the code there.

Comment: @wolf: I edited my answer and added a piece of code showing how the `Workbook_Open` event should look.

Comment: I want to lock Excel using the MAC address so I want to define 3 MAC addresses. Now how can I register 3 MAC addresses in code that only run on these?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, but Your code only locked excel in the first MAC address

Comment: @wolf: Are you using the function **as it is**? Couldn't you see that the constant is now: `Const test = "11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:34:32:55:23,34:45:45:33:33:11"` It is built from the three MAC addresses you wanted to be used. **Did you replace the generic addresses you posted with the real ones** to be tested? How do you test it? Do you have two computers and you built the constant using their MAC address? And the code does not **lock** Excel... It closes the workbook containing the code, if its IP is not in the constant `Test`, separated by comma.

Comment: I enter real MAC addresses. Also, changing the internet connection changes the MAC address, for example, Wi-Fi or adsl

Comment: @wolf: Yes. It is normal. But doesn't the code work as you need, if you input the correct MAC address?

Comment: @wolf:  Do you understand the above code and what my suggestion meant?

Comment: @FaneDuru  , Yes, it (your code)only validates the **first** MAC address.

Comment: @wolf:  This is not true! Please, copy here the string you use for `test` constant, against your active network MAC. And I asked you before and no answer: How do you test this?

Comment: CMD
ipconfig /all
Physical Address,
im copy your code in vbe and edite mac address

Comment: @wolf:  Please, can you do what I requested?

Comment: Must be a code.
Activate excel if one of the 3 mac address is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The machine may have more than one MAC address. You can retrieve them all, though I don't know if that is what you mean with "open Excel in all three MAC addresses".

```vb
' Constants.
'
    ' Count of bytes/octets in a MAC48 address.
    Const OctetCount    As Integer = 6
    ' Length of a byte (octet).
    Const OctetLength   As Integer = 2
    ' Count of digits in a MAC48 address.
    Const DigitCount    As Integer = OctetCount * OctetLength
    ' Possible count of frames.
    Const FrameCount1   As Integer = 1
    Const FrameCount3   As Integer = 3
    Const FrameCount6   As Integer = 6
    ' Length of the frames in a MAC address having one, three, or six frames.
    Const FrameLength1  As Integer = DigitCount / FrameCount1
    Const FrameLength3  As Integer = DigitCount / FrameCount3
    Const FrameLength6  As Integer = DigitCount / FrameCount6
    ' Lenght of a MAC address having one, three, or six frames.
    Const TotalLength1  As Integer = DigitCount + FrameCount1 - 1
    Const TotalLength3  As Integer = DigitCount + FrameCount3 - 1
    Const TotalLength6  As Integer = DigitCount + FrameCount6 - 1
    ' HexPattern of one hex digit ignoring case.
    Const HexPattern    As String = "[0-9,A-Fa-f]"



' Retrieves from the local computer an array of the NICs having a MAC address.
'
' The array has four dimensions:
'   0: Byte array. MAC address of the NIC
'   1: Boolean. The NIC is IP enabled
'   2: Boolean. The NIC has been assigned a default IP gateway
'   3: String. IP address (first if several)
'   4: String. Description of the NIC.
'
' Reference:
'   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration
'
' 2019-09-23, Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock
'
Public Function GetMacAddresses() As Variant()

    ' This computer.
    Const Computer      As String = "."
    ' Namespace to access the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class.
    Const NameSpace     As String = "\root\cimv2"
    ' Query to list IP enabled network adapters.
    Const Sql           As String = "Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where MACAddress Is Not Null"
    
    Dim WMIService      As Object
    Dim Adapters        As Object
    Dim Adapter         As Object
    
    Dim Octets(0 To OctetCount - 1) As Byte
    Dim Nics()          As Variant
    Dim PathName        As String
    Dim AdapterCount    As Long
    Dim Index           As Long
    
    PathName = "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & Computer & NameSpace
    Set WMIService = GetObject(PathName)
    
    ' Retrieve the list of network adapters having a MAC address.
    Set Adapters = WMIService.ExecQuery(Sql)
    AdapterCount = Adapters.Count
    
    If AdapterCount > 0 Then
        ' Array to hold:
        '   0: Byte array. MAC address of NIC
        '   1: Boolean. NIC is IP enabled
        '   2: Boolean. NIC has been assigned a default IP gateway
        '   3: String. IP address (first if several)
        '   4: String. NIC description
        ReDim Nics(0 To AdapterCount - 1, IpNicInformation.[_First] To IpNicInformation.[_Last])
        
        ' Loop the network adapters to fill the array.
        For Each Adapter In Adapters
            Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicMacAddress) = MacAddressParse(Adapter.MacAddress)
            Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicIpEnabled) = Adapter.IPEnabled
            Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicHasDefaultIpGateway) = Not IsNull(Adapter.DefaultIPGateway)
            If Not IsNull(Adapter.IPAddress) Then
                Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicIpAddress) = Adapter.IPAddress(0)
            End If
            Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicDescription) = Adapter.Description
            Index = Index + 1
        Next
    Else
        ' No adapter having a MAC address was found.
        ReDim Nics(0, IpNicInformation.[_First] To IpNicInformation.[_Last])
        Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicMacAddress) = Octets()
        Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicIpEnabled) = False
        Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicHasDefaultIpGateway) = False
        Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicIpAddress) = ""
        Nics(Index, IpNicInformation.ipNicDescription) = "N/A"
    End If
    
    GetMacAddresses = Nics

End Function
```

This is taken from my project [VBA.MacAddress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.MacAddress) holding much more code related to MAC addresses. One or more of these functions may be useful if you specify what you wish to achieve.

Comment: It looks that it wants to limit the access on the workbook to some specific MAC addresses. And his function was able to only check a single one.

Comment: What value will `OctetCount` have?

Comment: @FaneDuru: I've added the constants. Look up the project and the file `MacAddressCode.bas` and the link to the documentation for the full story.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function notMACAddress() As Boolean
    Dim m As String, arrMAC As Variant, El As Variant
    Const test = "11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:22:22:49:22,33:33:33:33:49:43"
    'add above the MAC string you need to be checked (separated by comma)
    
    arrMAC = Split(test, ",")
    m = GetMACAddress
    
    For Each El In arrMAC
        If m = El Then
            notMACAddress = False: Exit Function
        End If
    Next El
    notMACAddress = True
End Function

Function GetMACAddress() As String
    Dim sComputer As String
    Dim oWMIService As Object
    Dim cItems As Object
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim myMacAddress As String

    sComputer = "."

    Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set cItems = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

    For Each oItem In cItems
        If Not IsNull(oItem.IPAddress) Then myMacAddress = oItem.macAddress
        Exit For
    Next
    'it will return mac address in format MM:MM:MM:SS:SS:SS
    GetMACAddress = myMacAddress

End Function
Sub checkMACAddress()
    Debug.Print GetMACAddress
    Debug.Print notMACAddress
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If notMACAddress Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is one of the `test` constant elements separated by comma, the real MAC address to be validated by the function? The constant is not something magic. It must be built as I said: **''add above the MAC string you need to be checked (separated by comma)**... If it is, try please moving in another position (the second, the third) and you will see that it is found and accepted. I also asked: **How do you test this?**

Comment: Do you understand that the function return `False` in case of a MAC match? It returns `True` if any of the `test` elements matches computer running the code MAC address returned by `GetMACAddress`.